# Gradle SpringBoot Project : Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle, groovy

I am trying to build simple hello world spring-boot project with gradle and groovy. 
When I run 'gradle clean build', I am getting below error.

So far I tried,

1. Even though it is a gradle project, I updated the maven version to latest(3.6.3). Just to be a safer side.
2. I re-installed my intelliJ IDE
3. I added maven url as "https:" in build.gradle

After above steps, still I am getting below error. I am not sure what else I am missing.
Though I have given 'https:' url in gradle build file, I am not sure from where it is taking the non-secure url(http).

```
Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.1.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.1.RELEASE.
         > Could not get resource 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.1.RELEASE.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.1.RELEASE.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
```

---

And my gradle build file looks:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.own.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I figured out where to update the maven url to "https://*" for gradle projects.

```
$ vi ~/.gradle/init.gradle
```

then I updated the maven url to secure protocol ("https://...")

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            // Any Organization/Company specific repo url goes here
            maven {
                url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
            }
    }
}
```

#### After above steps, it worked for me and able to build the spring-boot application successfully.

Comment: This is what your question states and this is what you state in your qestion you have explicitly done.

Answer (score 1):

Using [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/), this is the content of the `build.gradle` generated there:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'groovy'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Note the major differences:

- `groovy` is actually there as plugin and as dependency
- the maven repo is secure.  As the error message states, you have use
  the https endpoint here

Comment: Thanks @cfrick for your prompt response. 
1. I copied your build.gradle file still it didn't work. 
2. And also, I tried adding groovy in plugins{} block at my existing build.gradle, but still no luck

Comment: Still, I am getting same error as mentioned in my initial question.
 Could not HEAD 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.3.1.RELEASE.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required

Comment: Are you behind some restrictive or corporation firewall, that prevents
you from downloading stuff like this?  E.g. have you tried to use that
URL there in your browser and make make sure it's https?

Comment: @cfrick, he is getting a http code 501 which is reflect that the HEAD method isn’t implemented by the server ( the repo Maven). So no issue with the firewall I guess?

Comment: thanks @cfrick and M.Mas for helping out on this case.
I searched in my system where else maven url was mentioned and found that it was added (by me, might be long back) in init.gradle.
Then, I updated there to secure url(https://*) and now build is successful.